# Load winforms icon from folder dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, icons

I need to change the winform icon to an icon found in a directory. This needs to work in the same way a web browser handles the loading of website icons.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Form.Icon` property?

Comment: Which icon do you need to change? Application icon? How does web browser relate to that?

Comment: No I have not tried using Form.Icon witch I'm working on testing now. The icon I need to change is the winforms application main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is going to be dynamic you can use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and monitor the  created and changed events in your Folder for your file changes.

```
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Name == "myIcon.ico")
    {
        this.Icon = new Icon(e.FullPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Icon property in constructor or Load event of form (make sure that icon exist in application directory):

```
Icon = new Icon("favicon.ico");
```